# How do I create draggable and resizable subwindows within a toplevel window in GTK+?

Tags: gtk, pygtk, gnome

My question seems very simple, but I failed to find an answer in the internet:

[image]

The picture is taken from Eclipse, which is implemented in GTK+ on Linux, so it should be theoretically possible, but I don't know, how. Probably not through setting gtk.Window type to gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL or gtk.WINDOW_POPUP.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure this is doable by defaut, although I didn't know the function unwind presented in his answer. But AFAIK, GNOME IDE, [Anjuta](http://www.anjuta.org/), uses some custom widgets to handle docking windows. You may want to give a look at [Anjuta's source code](http://git.gnome.org/browse/anjuta).

Answer (score 0):

You create scrolled widgets by embedding them in a [GtkScrolledWindow](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkScrolledWindow.html). You would create a resizable scrolled widget by embedding that inside [GtkHPaned](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkHPaned.html) and [GtkVPaned](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkVPaned.html) widgets.